# Reference One App_Code Class from Another

Tags: asp.net

Can I access one class in an App_Code sub folder from another (one being C# and the other VB) in an ASP .NET Web Site Project? I am not having any luck.

Comment: You mean to have one file in c# and one in VB and compile them and access them from the site ? Or what, I am not fully understand your question.

Comment: Sorry. For instance, I have Class A in an App_Code subfolder vbCode and Class B in csCode. I want to reference Class B inside Class A. Not in the site yet.

Comment: Do they compile or not at all ? (with out the reference from one to the other). If not you need to fix the web.config to compile them.

Comment: Any fix to this situation, @Erich ???

Comment: @Anil No. I was not able to do it. So I converted all the classes in the vbCode folder to C#.